# importing large data from excel to Oracle efficiently

Tags: excel, oracle, performance

I have table of 20 columns in oracle db which contains records more than 150K rows. I selected all records and exported instance of Excel sheet. Also exported as Insert statements.

I created the duplicate table with another name of same table for inserting records. (I have to do this on different machine and environment, just testing on same db schema)

In Excel format while importing through Database -> Import -> Import Table Data is taking taking long time to just view the records of 25K rows, while with 150K Toad not responded.

In other way of Insert statements, I have to break number lines so I don't get memory exception while running insert statement of having more than 200K lines.

Can any one suggest efficient and best way to export records from excel to oracle table?

Comment: Write an insert script with the data in?

Comment: @Matt can explain how ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm

Comment: What tool are you using, toad? Also, you could bypass the problem by using CSV over XLSX, proby

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I am using toad. but Import table doesnt have option for .csv, it has .xls, .txt, .dbf, .mdb, clipboard

Comment: i can help you if you're using Oracle tools, might want to post your question to the toad forums (or try the txt method, i think that will work for your csv)

Comment: If you want to keep table names same on different machine and environment then in SQLPlus, you can try using `exp`,`imp` commands for exporting and importing `dmp` files.